# Javascript onmouseUp without hold

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set event listener onmouseUp.

I want to make difference between onmouseUp in short time (just click) and onmouseUp after holding lets say more than one second OR onmouseDown with mouseMove together.

Reason:

I'm listening button number 2 (which == 2), and i want to have function onclick to center something and zoom something with holding button2 and moving mouse up/down. But not to do it both in one time.

Is it possible in JS or jQuery with any integrated method?

Answer (score 2):

Get [NOW](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/) on [Mouse Down](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)

Get [NOW](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/) on [Mouse Up](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/)

```
var start = 0;
$('#button').mousedown(function () {
    start = $.now();
});
$('#button').mouseup(function () {
    end = $.now();
    $('#output').html(end - start);
    if (end - start > 1000) {
        alert('you just held the mouse for 1 second');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/wurcy7s1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the time that was spent for the action before mouse is up:

E.g.:

```
$(<your_element>).on(<your_event_type>, function(e) {
    start = new Date().getTime();
});
```

Then do a similar thing for the other event type and calculate a `stop` value.

Compute the difference `stop - start` and make a decision.

This will also cover the case when the mouse is moved while the click is pressed ( because it is bigger than a specified threshold ). But if you want to check that mouse was moved, you can use its coordinates (`e.pageX` and `e.pageY`).